# If $AB=BA$, then is every eigenvalue of $AB$ is the product of some eigenvalue of $A$ with some eigenvalue of $B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are two complex square matrices such that $AB=BA$. Then it is known that $A$ and $B$ have a common eigenvector. If we let $v$ such a common eigenvector, with $Av=cv$ and $Bv=dv$, then we have $ABv=dAv=cdv$, so $v$ is an eigenvector of $AB$ with eigenvalue $cd$.

Then, my question is about its converse: If $w$ is an eigenvector of $AB=BA$ with $ABw=ew$, then is  $e$ the product of some eigenvalue of $A$ with some eigenvalue of $B$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

Since $A$ and $B$ are two complex square matrices, both $A$ and $B$ are triangularisable. We also supposed that $AB=BA$, and we know that this implies that $A$ and $B$ are [simultaneously triangularisable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix#Simultaneous_triangularisability). Can you finish?